# Significance of Equal To in Binary Search

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

I am implementing binary search in C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int bs(vector<int> a, int val)
{
    int l =0, r = a.size()-1;
    while(l<=r) // Significance of ==
    {
        int mid = l + (r-l)/2;

        if(a[mid]==val) return mid;
        if(a[mid]>val)
        {
            r = mid-1; continue;
        }
        else
        {
            l = mid + 1 ;
        }
    }
   return l; // Deliberately returning this
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> a = {1,3};
  cout << bs(a,1) <<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Question 1**

In some implementations, I see people use

```
while(l<r)
```

while in some they use

```
while(l<=r)
```

Is there any conceptual difference between preferring one way ? Any possible sources of error if I don't use == ?

**Question 2**

In case the element is not found, is l guaranteed to be the position in which the element could be inserted so that the list still remains sorted ?  Is this valid while using equal to or not using equal to ?

Comment: why downvote, it is a good question, i showed what i tried.

Comment: `while(l<r)` wouldn't work in your implementation, because the last vector element won't be within the search range.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are calculating variable `r`.
In your case

```
r = a.size()-1;
```

So correct usage is `while(l<=r)`

If you calculate r as `r = a.size();` correct usage is `while(l<r)`

> In case the element is not found, is l guaranteed to be the position
>   in which the element could be inserted so that the list still remains
>   sorted ?

You didn't sort your vector, for proper binary search, vector should be sorted before calling binary search.

```
std::sort(std::begin(a),std::end(a));
```

And  header provide a `std::binary_search`, so instead reinventing the wheel you can use it as follows:

```
   std::binary_search(std::begin(a),std::end(a),val);
```

Binary search supposed to return value of index in vector, if it find. But there is no guarantee it should provide the next location for insertion.

> Is this valid while using equal to or not using equal to ?

I explained it in first part of my answer.

Comment: Plz Thanks a lot. So, list[r] will be excluded from search in that case ? plz see the question 2 also. Merci .